# Error when using mail-listener2 "Error: Timeout: No verification email received."

Tags: javascript, email, gmail

Using **mail-listener2**
I have this code and received an error. I tried increasing the authTimeout but it doesn't work. I checked the password and it's also correct. Any idea what could be the problem?

**Script:**

```
const MailListener = require('mail-listener2');

const emailConfig = {
    username: 'myemail@gmail.com',
    password: 'password',
    host: 'imap.gmail.com',
    port: 993, 
    secure: true, 
    mailbox: 'INBOX', 
    authTimeout: 30000
};

async function fetchVerificationCode() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const mailListener = new MailListener(emailConfig);

    mailListener.on('server:connected', () => {
        console.log('Connected to email server');
    });

    mailListener.on('mail', (mail) => {
    
        const verificationCode = extractVerificationCodeFromEmail(mail.html || mail.text);
        mailListener.stop(); // Detener la escucha de nuevos correos electrónicos
        resolve(verificationCode);
    });

    mailListener.on('error', (err) => {
        mailListener.stop(); // Detener la escucha en caso de error
        reject(err);
    });

    mailListener.on('end', () => {
        console.log('Email server connection closed');
    });

    mailListener.start(); // Iniciar la escucha de nuevos correos electrónicos

    
    setTimeout(() => {
        mailListener.stop();
        reject(new Error('Timeout: No verification email received.'));
    }, 30000);
    });
}

function extractVerificationCodeFromEmail(emailContent) {
  
    return '123456';
}
fetchVerificationCode()
module.exports = fetchVerificationCode;
```

**Error:**

```
reject(new Error('Timeout: No verification email received.'));
               ^

Error: Timeout: No verification email received.
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/Users/name/Documents/Project/project/cypress/support/emailChecker.js:97:16)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)
```

I tried changing the wait time.
Expect to `extractVerificationCodeFromEmail()` return `123456`